Как переключиться на другое окно python?
У меня создано отдельным файлом меню и отдельно основной код игры. Подскажите как сделать переключение между экранами файлов. Чтобы при нажатии кнопки меню "Играть" открывалось окно с игрой.
Вот код меню:
from time import sleep
import pygame
import pygame_menu
from pygame_menu import themes

pygame.init()
surface = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 450))

def set_difficulty(value, difficulty):
 print(value)
 print(difficulty)

def start_the_game():
 mainmenu._open(loading)
 pygame.time.set_timer(update_loading, 30)

mainmenu = pygame_menu.Menu('Welcome', 800, 450, theme=themes.THEME_SOLARIZED)
mainmenu.add.text_input('Имя: ', default='username')
mainmenu.add.button('Играть', start_the_game)
mainmenu.add.button('Выйти', pygame_menu.events.EXIT)

loading = pygame_menu.Menu('Loading the Game...', 800, 450, theme=themes.THEME_DARK)
loading.add.progress_bar("Progress", progressbar_id = "1", default=0, width = 200, )

arrow = pygame_menu.widgets.LeftArrowSelection(arrow_size = (10, 15))

update_loading = pygame.USEREVENT + 0

while True:
    events = pygame.event.get()
    for event in events:
    if event.type == update_loading:
    progress = loading.get_widget("1")
    progress.set_value(progress.get_value() + 1)
    if progress.get_value() == 100:
    pygame.time.set_timer(update_loading, 0)
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
    exit()
    
    if mainmenu.is_enabled():
    mainmenu.update(events)
    mainmenu.draw(surface)
    if (mainmenu.get_current().get_selected_widget()):
    arrow.draw(surface, mainmenu.get_current().get_selected_widget())
    
    pygame.display.update()

